# Get mypy to accept subtype of generic type as a method argument

Tags: python, generics, mypy

I'm trying to extract a pattern that we are using in our code base into a more generic, reusable construct. However, I can't seem to get the generic type annotations to work with mypy.

Here's what I got:

```
from abc import (
    ABC,
    abstractmethod
)
import asyncio
import contextlib
from typing import (
    Any,
    Iterator,
    Generic,
    TypeVar
)

_TMsg = TypeVar('_TMsg')

class MsgQueueExposer(ABC, Generic[_TMsg]):

    @abstractmethod
    def subscribe(self, subscriber: 'MsgQueueSubscriber[_TMsg]') -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError("Must be implemented by subclasses")

    @abstractmethod
    def unsubscribe(self, subscriber: 'MsgQueueSubscriber[_TMsg]') -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError("Must be implemented by subclasses")


class MsgQueueSubscriber(Generic[_TMsg]):

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def subscribe(
            self,
            msg_queue_exposer: MsgQueueExposer[_TMsg]) -> Iterator[None]:
        msg_queue_exposer.subscribe(self)
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            msg_queue_exposer.unsubscribe(self)


class DemoMsgQueSubscriber(MsgQueueSubscriber[int]):
    pass

class DemoMsgQueueExposer(MsgQueueExposer[int]):

    # The following works for mypy:

    # def subscribe(self, subscriber: MsgQueueSubscriber[int]) -> None:
    #     pass

    # def unsubscribe(self, subscriber: MsgQueueSubscriber[int]) -> None:
    #     pass

    # This doesn't work but I want it to work :)

    def subscribe(self, subscriber: DemoMsgQueSubscriber) -> None:
        pass

    def unsubscribe(self, subscriber: DemoMsgQueSubscriber) -> None:
        pass
```

I commented out some code that works but doesn't quite fulfill my needs. Basically I want that the `DemoMsgQueueExposer` accepts a `DemoMsgQueSubscriber` in its `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` methods. The code type checks just fine if I use `MsgQueueSubscriber[int]` as a type but I want it to accept subtypes of that.

I keep running into the following error.

```
generic_msg_queue.py:55: error: Argument 1 of "subscribe" incompatible with supertype "MsgQueueExposer"
```

I feel that this has something to do with co-/contravariants but I tried several things before I gave up and came here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bets are either to 1) just delete `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` from `MsgQueueExposer` altogether, or 2) make `MsgQueueExposer` generic with respect to the *subscriber*, either in addition to or instead of the `msg`.

Here is an example of what approach 2 might look like, assuming we want to keep the `_TMsg` type parameter. Note that I added a `messages()` method for demonstration purposes:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import asyncio
import contextlib
from typing import Any, Iterator, Generic, TypeVar, List

_TMsg = TypeVar('_TMsg')
_TSubscriber = TypeVar('_TSubscriber', bound='MsgQueueSubscriber')

class MsgQueueExposer(ABC, Generic[_TSubscriber, _TMsg]):

    @abstractmethod
    def subscribe(self, subscriber: _TSubscriber) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError("Must be implemented by subclasses")

    @abstractmethod
    def unsubscribe(self, subscriber: _TSubscriber) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError("Must be implemented by subclasses")

    @abstractmethod
    def messages(self) -> List[_TMsg]:
        raise NotImplementedError("Must be implemented by subclasses")


class MsgQueueSubscriber(Generic[_TMsg]):
    # Note that we are annotating the 'self' parameter here, so we can
    # capture the subclass's exact type.

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def subscribe(
            self: _TSubscriber,
            msg_queue_exposer: MsgQueueExposer[_TSubscriber, _TMsg]) -> Iterator[None]:
        msg_queue_exposer.subscribe(self)
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            msg_queue_exposer.unsubscribe(self)


class DemoMsgQueSubscriber(MsgQueueSubscriber[int]):
    pass

class DemoMsgQueueExposer(MsgQueueExposer[DemoMsgQueSubscriber, int]):
    def subscribe(self, subscriber: DemoMsgQueSubscriber) -> None:
        pass

    def unsubscribe(self, subscriber: DemoMsgQueSubscriber) -> None:
        pass

    def messages(self) -> List[int]:
        pass
```

More broadly, we wanted to express the idea that each `MsgQueueExposer` works only for a specific kind of subscriber, so we needed to encode that information somewhere.

The one hole in this is that mypy will not be able to make sure when you're using `MsgQueueExposer` that whatever type the subscriber receives and that whatever type the exposer is expecting will agree. So, if we defined the demo subscriber as `class DemoMsgQueSubscriber(MsgQueueSubscriber[str])` but kept `DemoMsgQueueExposer` the same, mypy would be unable to detect this mistake.

But I'm assuming you're always going to be creating a new subscriber and a new exposer in pairs and is something you can carefully audit, so this mistake is probably unlikely to occur in practice.

Comment: Great answer! A follow up regarding:


>"mypy would be unable to detect this mistake".


This is because the `MsqQueueExposer` is basically with an `MsgQueSubscriber[Any]` because the type system doesn't allow us to define something like `_TSubscriber[_TMsg]` right?

Comment: And regarding 1) How could I remove these two methods from the `MsgQueueExposer` and still provide a generic building block `MsgQueueSubscriber` that assumes that `subscribe` / `unsubscribe` exist?

Comment: @Christoph -- Regarding your follow-up question: yes, that's correct. Regarding strategy 1: I don't think you can. I mentioned that strategy mostly for the sake of completeness.